# Как изменить цвет заливки svg при onScroll?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg, анимация

Могу ли я изменить цвет заливки логотипа SVG при `onScroll`?
 Это возможно с `html` или  свойством `css`?
 Изменение цвета должно быть при прокрутке, когда курсор находится на другом `DIV`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53674509/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Идея состоит в том, чтобы использовать правила CSS: `mix-blend-mode: difference;` и `isolation: isolate;` для группы.
 Вам решать, как вы хотите перемещать слои.
 Я использую диапазон `input type` для этого.

*Я надеюсь, код ниже поможет.*

```js
percent.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  let val = ~~(percent.value);
  let _var = map(100-val,0,100,3,27);
  txt.textContent = val+"%";
  pth.setAttributeNS(null,"d",`M3,27H27V${_var}H3z`)
})

function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; font-size:10px; background:lightblue}
[type="range"]{width:150px;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="150">
  <g style="isolation: isolate;">
  <path d="M3,27H27V3H3z" fill="white" />
  <path id="pth" d="M3,27H27V15H3z"  />
  <text id="txt" x="15" y="15" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" style="mix-blend-mode: difference;">50%</text>
  </g>
</svg>


<p><input id="percent" type="range" value="50" /></p>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53675446/7394871)